# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

Tags: java, jenkins

I am using 'jenkins-client-0.20.jar' and programming in java to connect to Jenkins and extract few information like list of jobs, nodes, active nodes, projects etc. I wrote below piece of code by referring "https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api" link. On compiling I am getting error as below

```
import com.offbytwo.jenkins.*;
import com.offbytwo.jenkins.client.*;
import com.offbytwo.jenkins.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Map;

public class NewTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        JenkinsServer server = new JenkinsServer(new URI("https://my-jenkins.abc.com/jenkins/"), "admin", "admin");
        Map<String, Job> jobs = server.getJobs();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Job> entry : jobs.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }

    }
}



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at NewTest.main(NewTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I have following jars in my eclipse.

[image]

How do I fix this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `google-collections-1.0.jar` to your classpath. This contains the class `com.google.common.base.Function`

BTW: This Project is a maven projekt. So oyu should use maven to build your Project

Comment: `google-collections-1.0` has been supplanted by Guava many, many years ago.  (Possibly even a decade?)

Comment: @LouisWasserman But this jar contains the class wich is needed, so why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I imported 'google-collections-1.0-rc5.jar' file and the error went away but it came with a new error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpResponseException" for the same line of code.

Comment: @Raji Then you have to add commons-httpclient.jar too.

Comment: Did that. Some other error popped up. I will use maven and resolve dependency as you explained in your first comment. Thanks a lot. :)